# open files from internal memory in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using following code to write data in /data/data/com.abc.def/files/ directory.

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    fos.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Use following code to open file via intent.

```
File file = getDir(file_name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
```

but it gives error like "**There is a problem parsing the package**"

[image]
please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S II running Android version 2.3.3, and when I try to install a package I get the error "Parse Error". I use Android 3.2 to make these packages.

You are trying to open a 3.2 application on a 2.3.3 device.

Solution

Change the required API level tag android:minSdkVersion from the manifest file

or remove the required API level tag android:minSdkVersion.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to internal memory, not external

Comment: i use internal memory not external.

Comment: but how to open that file. for example if there is a .apk file in my internal memory, i want to install it using intent.

Answer (score 0):

What is the level of API that your using ??  Try using 8+ (Froyo or above)

---

### Edit

Add this line to you manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

or

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

so that you may compile in higher and run in lower version

Comment: I dont have 50 points, so i cant comment on a post  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127348/how-to-add-comments-in-stackoverflow

Comment: Edit your answer and provide some explanation.

Comment: @Dharmendra
I have edited the answer but now i have enough points to comment
So what should i do now ? Should i delete this ?

Comment: Nope no need to delete if you are answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

```
String fileName = "tmp.apk";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName,
        MODE_WORLD_READABLE | MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

// write the .apk content here ... flush() and close()

// Now start the standard instalation window
File fileLocation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileLocation),
                       "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```